# VBA get all occurences of a style in a Word document from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

For my work I have to find all the instances of a style in 40 word documents (.doc). Once I get the text, I want to write it in a cell in my excel sheet (.xls).

With the code I wrote I can get the first instance of that style but I cannot get the next one, it goes into an infinite loop and I don't now why (there are about 10 occurrences on each file).

Could you tell me where I am wrong?

I want to go from that:
[Before running the macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysgfe.jpg)
to that:
[After running the macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs1nz.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
'==================================================================
' Declarations
'==================================================================

Dim ObjWord As Object ' Word application object

'==================================================================
' Macro
'==================================================================

Public Sub Macro()

Dim row As Integer
row = 9 'first available row

Set ObjWord = CreateObject("word.application")

Worksheets("Sheet 2").Activate

While (Cells(row, 2).Value <> "End of file list")

    Set file = ObjWord.documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.path & ".\" & Cells(row, 1).Hyperlinks(1).Address)


    Set currentRange = file.Range

    currentRange.Find.ClearFormatting
    currentRange.Find.Forward = True
    currentRange.Find.Text = ""
    currentRange.Find.Style = "MyStyle"
    bFind = currentRange.Find.Execute

    Do While bFind 'here is the endless loop
         row = row + 1
         StyleValue= currentRange.Text 'I get stuck with the first value :-(
         Rows(row).EntireRow.Insert
         Cells(row, 2).Value = StyleValue
         bFind = currentRange.Find.Execute
    Loop

    file.Close

    row = row + 1 ' next File
Wend

ObjWord.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: How `Find` reacts depends to a certain extent on where the found text is located in respect to certain document structures. Particularly critical is when table cells are involved. Another potential problem I see in your code is VBA (and us) not being sure when it's dealing with Excel objects and when with Word objects. `Range` is used in both, for example, as are `rows` and `columns`. You need to provide some clarification in order for use to be able to clearly answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make a number of changes to get it to work for me, mostly because I have `Option Explicit` on and declare all variables.

However while going through it something that may be the issue if it is looping on the first find, is that you have to move the selection past the find to find the next one.

```
Do While bFind 'here is the endless loop
    row = row + 1
    StyleValue= currentRange.Text 'I get stuck with the first value :-(
    Rows(row).EntireRow.Insert
    Cells(row, 2).Value = StyleValue

    currentRange.SetRange currentRange.End, currentRange.End

    bFind = currentRange.Find.Execute
Loop
```

If that doesn't work I can pop up a full replacement later

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly. I tried something like that before but I guess I did it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think it needs to be this:

```
Do While currentRange.Find.Found 
    currentRange.Find.Execute 
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks Charlie but it does not work, the issue is still the same :(

Comment: OK than I think the issue is with Excel - try removing all Excel lines e.g. Rows(row).EntireRow.Insert. If that works than I can provide a workaround.

Comment: That hasn't changed a bit.

Comment: I'm not sure find works on a file.Range - if you copy the file contents into Word and then try it using Document.Range does that work? Find works by changing the active text selection which I'm not sure it can do on a file.